# Accessing image view from a different View Controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have two view controller classes along with two views in my storyboard file. One is named ViewController and the other one is named SettingsViewController because it's settings for the first view. I have a UISwitch on the Settings view and I want it to change the image view that is in the ViewController class. How can I access that from my Settings class and change the image of the image view? I already tried importing the ViewController class and synthesizing the image view but it says that the image view must be declared in the ViewController class.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SettingsViewController:

```
.h file
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;

.m file
@implementation SettingsViewController {

@synthesize imageView;
```

Now in your ViewController, you need to implement the prepareForSegue method:

```
.m file

#import "SettingsViewController"

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"goToSettingsSegue"]) {
        SettingsViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
        dest.imageView = self.imageView; //set the image in your view as the image in the settings view
    }
}
```

Now you should have access to it in the settings view.

Comment: Now it says "Property 'imageView' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'" on the line dest.imageView = self.imageView;.

Comment: Have you declared an outlet for your imageView in the ViewController class? Ctrl + Drag the UIImageView from your storyboard to the header file of the ViewController class, and name it "imageView".

Comment: Thank you. But I think you may have misunderstood my question. I want it so if the switch in the settings view controller is on, it calls a method.

Comment: My comment was referring to the error that you described above, where the imageView property wasn't found on your ViewController. The code that I posted in my answer won't work unless you have an outlet from your UIImageView to your ViewController. Once you have that, you can pass the reference to your UIImageView to the settings view, using the process I described above. Once you have a reference to it in your SettingsViewController, you can call a method when the switch is pushed, and from that method you can change the image.